# "Зазіхач". Чи існує/чи питоме це слово?

Tags: українські-словники, розмовна-українська, існування-слова

Чому питаю:

Ані [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zazikhach), ані [англійсько-українські словники](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87&dicts=8&highlight=on), ані [словники України онлайн](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87), ані [офіційний сайт української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87&t=0), ані [російсько-українські словники](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) не знаходять такого слова.

Разом з тим, МЕНІ воно звучить ну дуже орґанічно.

Менше зі мною, [google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87) видає 6 результатів для цього слова.

Просто [ґуґл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?hl=uk&source=hp&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87%22&oq=&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.35i39k1l6.683.3381.0.5573.11.10.0.0.0.0.130.961.3j6.9.0.foo%2Cnso-ehuqi%3D1%2Cnso-ehuui%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-mplt%3D2%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1701%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-05%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-17%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-54%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-0602%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-007525%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-052675...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.9.959.6..0j0i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i7i10i30k1.ZIrUOsn8Du4) видає 221 результат.

Якщо б сам лише ґуґл, то ще подумав би, що люди самостійно використовують, і то рідко. Тобто, не арґумент, а от у книгах - це вже треба розбиратися.

[Корпус української мови](http://www.mova.info/corpus2.aspx?tid=35322) знаходить це слово лише у книзі 2013 року:

`Найвірогідніше, така швидкість зумовлювалася побоюванням, аби потенційний зазіхач на капіталістичне добро не встиг отямитися і передумати.`

Допоможіть розібратися, будь ласка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Новотвір. Олександр Стишов у книзі «Українська лексика кінця двадцятого століття» (2005, «Пугач») пише ([ст. 126–127](//books.google.com/books?id=sbHqAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87)):

> Досить значну за обсягом групу сформували віддієслівні новотвори з дериваційним значенням "носій процесуальної ознаки". Вони утворилися переважно від дієслів недоконаного виду, найчастіше префіксальних, за допомогою суфікса *-ач*, і поповнили два словотвірні типи: (1) агентиви на означення осіб як виконавців дії: *зцілювач*, *рекомендувач*, *пильнувач*, *утримувач*, *продукувач*, *впроваджувач*, *пожертвувач* та ін. (пор. *Це лінія першого в Україні впроваджувача щільникового зв'язку … (Тел, 18.09.97)*); (2) агентиви на означення особи як носія певної процесуальної ознаки, що характеризує її поведінку, вдачу: *обожнювач*, *поціновувач*, *поцікавлювач*, *обдумувач*, *випрохувач*, *викривлювач*, *вислугач*, ***зазіхач*** [виділення моє] тощо (пор.: *… триває бій за Україну проти колишніх колонізаторів, їхніх вислугачів та всяких інших українофобів (Д, 06.01. 99)*), хоч не всі вони бездоганні за своєю формою, що впливає на перспективи їх функціонування. Xарактерно, що серед цих новотворів чимало власне українських правничих термінів *розслідувач*, *дізнавач*, *стягувач* ((1) "той, хто здійснює виконання рішення суду про стягнення"; (2) "особа, на чию користь стягують кошти, майно"), *вимагач* тощо, напр.: *Багато клопотів працівникам міліції останнього тижня додали вимагачі (Р, 02.04.99)*.

Але, як на мене, достатньо органічний. Вже використовується в посібниках для шкільних вчителів — Віра Когут, ‎Наталія Демчук «Уроки української літератури. 5 клас. Посібник для вчителя» (Тернопіль, «Навчальна книга — Богдан»):

> **Золота липа (бережанська легенда)**
>
> <…> Але на чуже добро завжди знайдеться **зазіхач** [виділення моє]. <…>

Є й старіші вжитки:

- Потім зазіхач послухався, але не подався геть. <sub>//[З журналу «Донбас» (1970)](//books.google.com/books?id=4P8iAQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87).</sub>
- Все в тих оповідях виходило так, що мусить щезнути з нашої землі чужинець, що має знову вернутися людям воля, бо, скільки існує життя, жоден зазіхач на чуже щастя сам не лишався щасливим. <sub>//[Микола Кирильчук, роман «Джерело» (1973, Київ, «Радянський письменник»)](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=kE4-AQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87).</sub>

Є й словники різного ступеню серйозності, що містять це слово ([ABBYY Lingvo](//www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/en-uk/insader), [Dictionarist](http://uk.dictionarist.com/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%87), [WordHippo](//www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/ukrainian-word-27acc8e0307878da87ff82a96665c3a0967719e0.html), [Synonymfinder.net](http://uk.synonymfinder.net/sinonimiv/z/zgarbnik)) або обговорюють включення цього слова ([народний на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4654)).

P.S.: В обговоренні на R2U (див. посилання вище) є цікаві альтернативи:

- заздрісник;
- ласий (заздрий) на [мій варіант — до].

Вони не завжди доречні, але, наприклад, «найвірогідніше, така швидкість зумовлювалася побоюванням, аби потенційний зазіхач на капіталістичне добро не встиг отямитися і передумати» цілком можна сказати як «найімовірніше, така квапливість зумовлювалася побоюванням, що ласі до капіталістичного добра (на капіталістичне добро) можуть (встигнуть) отямитися й передумати». Upd.: Подивився [контекст](http://lib.rus.ec/b/524284/read) — все-таки «зазіхач» там доречніше, бо там це кажуть із певною іронією про людину, що найімовірніше не є аніяким зазіхачем, а з «ласим» ця іронія, мені здається, втрачається.